# Problem selecting class using jquery

Tags: jquery, multithreading, comments, css-selectors, each

I've been banging my head against a wall trying make this work for a while now. I'm trying to shorten the comment body to one line for compact comment preview. I'm using jquery .each function to go through each .cbody (comment body) in my threaded comment system and place it in the cshort div inside chead. It should work but i cant select the cshort class in the top line. Any help is very appreciated. As far as i can see my jquery should be this:

```
$('.cbody').each(function(Ind1){
         var str = $(this).text();
         $(this).parent().siblings('.chead').next('.cshort').html(str); 
    });
});
```

This is the html for the comment:

```
<ul>
<li>
<div id="23">
<a name="23">
</a>
<div class="chead">
<a href="#" class="unord">
<img src="images/plus.gif" border="0">
</a>
<a href="userinfo.php?user=muuuuuuuu">
<img src="include/avatar/n.jpg" border="0">
</a>
<span style="display: none;" class="uname">
usersname
</span>
&nbsp;,

<span class="cshort">
</span>
<span class="votes_up" id="votes_up23">
2
</span>
-
<span class="votes_down" id="votes_down23">
0
</span>
<span class="vote_buttons" id="vote_buttons23">
<a href="javascript:;" class="vote_up" id="23">
</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="vote_down" id="23">
</a>
</span>
</div>
<div class="cbody">
<br>
The comment text funny lol
</div>
<a style="display: none;" href="#" class="reply" id="23">
Reply
</a>
<a style="display: none;" href="#21" class="cparent">
Parent
</a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the cbody's parent appears to have no siblings, so the bit

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.chead')
```

is not returning anything, you most likely want either

```
$(this).parent().find('.chead')
```

or

```
$(this).siblings('.chead')
```

to get most directly to the cshort, use

```
$(this).parent().find('.cshort')
```

Edit:

Your HTML's hierarchy looks like this:

```
ul
| li
| | div#23
| | | a
| | | div.chead
| | | div.cbody
| | | ...
```

- `$(this)` refers to the cbody
- `$(this).parent()` refers to div#23
- `$(this).parent().siblings()` returns all other child nodes of the `li` (empty in your sample code's case)
- `$(this).siblings()` refers to div.chead, and a few `a` elements

since chead is a sibling of cbody, the best way to select it is with

```
$(this).siblings('.chead')
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that sorted it. Could you explain why the cbody parent div has no siblings? Is chead not a siblings?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.chead').next('.cshort').html(str);
```

to this:

```
$(this).siblings('.chead').children('.cshort').html(str);
```

`.chead` and `.cbody` are siblings, so you don't need to look at `.cbody`'s parent. Also, `.cshort` is a child of `.chead`, so you look through `.chead`'s children, not at its siblings (via `.next`).

Comment: Thanks, your method works as well, i gave the correct answer to cobbal as he was fractionally quicker, upvoted you though.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that last method be append?

.html(str) will be replacing it each time, and you'll only end up with the last one.